# Ansys multiphysics import deformed mesh to HFSS

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, radio

I want to run a coupled simulation in Ansys - RF heating and deformation of waveguide. Pictures of project layout and settings are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAmdl.jpg).

I calculated RF fields and surface losses in HFSS; imported them to steady-state thermal, calculated temperature of the waveguide; calculated structure deformation in static structural. Now what is needed is to run this problem until it converges. But for some reason HSFF does not import calculated deformed mesh from static structural. What else should I do to make it import mesh? Can I then use feedback iterator to automatically recalculate this problem?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem than you. Did you solved it? could you import the deformed mesh to HFSS?
Thanks!

Comment: @Carl, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with workbench setup. Static structural node should be placed **over** thermal node, not near it. More detailed description with pictures is avaliable [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuHHZ.jpg).

Comment: thank you for your help. I am trying to follow your instuctions. Is there any way I can get the Ansys files of your example for a better understanding?

Comment: @Carl you can reach me on [here](https://imgur.com/user/seregaxvm/about)